# Looping through object for unique names result with odd behaviour

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to output unique language names from this, example object of users:

```
var users = [
  {
    username: 'Alex',
    favoriteLanguages: ['JavaScript', 'JavaScript', 'C++'],
  },
  {
    username: 'Bob',
    favoriteLanguages: ['JavaScript', 'JavaScript', 'PHP'],
  },
  {
    username: 'Mia',
    favoriteLanguages: ['JavaScript', 'JavaScript', 'JavaScript', 'JavaScript'],
  },
  {
    username: 'David',
    favoriteLanguages: ['C#', 'C++', 'JavaScript'],
  },
  {
    username: 'Lee',
    favoriteLanguages: ['JavaScript', 'JavaScript', 'Swift'],
  }
];
```

I did manage to output unique language names by doing this:

```js
var users = [
  {
    username: 'Alex',
    favoriteLanguages: ['JavaScript', 'JavaScript', 'C++'],
  },
  {
    username: 'Bob',
    favoriteLanguages: ['JavaScript', 'JavaScript', 'PHP'],
  },
  {
    username: 'Mia',
    favoriteLanguages: ['JavaScript', 'JavaScript', 'JavaScript', 'JavaScript'],
  },
  {
    username: 'David',
    favoriteLanguages: ['C#', 'C++', 'JavaScript'],
  },
  {
    username: 'Lee',
    favoriteLanguages: ['JavaScript', 'JavaScript', 'Swift'],
  }
];

function allLanguages() {
    var temp = {} // changed
    var final = []
    users.forEach(function(val){
        for(var i in val["favoriteLanguages"]){
            var l = val["favoriteLanguages"]
            if(typeof(temp[l[i]]) == "undefined"){
                final.push(l[i])
            }
            temp[l[i]] = 0
            console.log(temp)
        }
    })
    //console.log("temp: " + temp)
    //console.log("final: " + final)
}

allLanguages();
```

However, I don't quite get why am I getting a full object of languages in the `temp` right away, from iteration 0... It start to output to the console from this:

```
[JavaScript: 0]
C#
:
0
C++
:
0
JavaScript
:
0
PHP
:
0
Swift
:
0
```

And I really don't get it, shouldn't it output one by one, so to say by each of the `[l[i]]`, and not all of them straight away... I actually don't understand now how am I able to output the correct results in the `final`.

Would appreciate any help to understand this.

Comment: You're using `temp` as a lookup table. Why is it initialized as an array?

Comment: @NinaScholz Hi Nina :) From all. and I'm actually getting them by the function above, but I lost my self in how am I getting this, because the `temp` start to hold everything from iteration 0, and I didn't plan it and don't actually understand why it is happening

Comment: @melpomene it should be an obj, sorry for that :/ But it is still the same, it outputs(for the `temp`) everything straight away

Comment: @danedidug I can’t reproduce your console output. I only get `0` for the first log, `temp: ` for the second, and `final: JavaScript,C++,PHP,C#,Swift` for the last one. If you wanted to reset `temp` with every new user, you’d need to redefine `temp = {};` and `final = [];` before the `for` loop. You probably don’t even need both variables. You could just do `val.favoriteLanguages = Array.from(new Set(val.favoriteLanguages));` in the callback…

Comment: Your code only outputs `final: JavaScript,C++,PHP,C#,Swift`. I don't understand where that other stuff comes from.

Comment: @melpomene try to comment the `console.log("final: " + final)` and uncomment the `console.log(temp.length)`.

Comment: Now it says `undefined` `undefined` `undefined` `undefined` `undefined` `undefined`.

Comment: @melpomene sorry, I just messed with the copying etc... edit the question. basically it should've been `console.log(temp)`. Now you could see it

Comment: @Xufox I just tried from scratch - same thing :/ It outputs all the languages :/

Comment: Now it accumulates gradually, starting from `{
  "JavaScript": 0
}`.

Comment: Perhaps I should get you an image of what I actually see... would this help you understand it?

Comment: @melpomene but if I open it, I can see the: `C#
:
0
C++
:
0
JavaScript
:
0
PHP
:
0
Swift
:
0` so it's normal to see them like so? why?!

Comment: Open what? Are you not clicking on the *Run code snippet* button?

Comment: @melpomene here's an image of it, I basically click the arrow https://image.ibb.co/dmmiEn/fffnl.png

Comment: The first line is the actual output; the stuff below is a live view of the object, which (since the function has finished) has its final contents.

Comment: @melpomene ok, but why the live view of the object contain only the `C#
:
0
C++
:
0
JavaScript
:
0
PHP
:
0
Swift
:
0`?

Comment: What else did you expect it to contain?

Comment: @melpomene basically the same, just without the whole `C# : 0 C++ : 0 JavaScript : 0 PHP : 0 Swift : 0`... it should go to the javascript and put it to the final and to the temp with the 0, then it should go to check another javascript and again put javascript is 0 to the temp, checks for the c++, puts it to the final and temp with the 0 and so on, but without the whole bunch of `C# : 0 C++ : 0 JavaScript : 0 PHP : 0 Swift : 0` from the beginning... I feel really dumb, but I don't understand why it is there :/

Comment: That's exactly what it does (and that's what the output shows if you don't click on the down arrow). What the live object view shows you is not a snapshot or copy of `temp` at the time of `console.log`, it is the actual `temp` variable. Since you're only inspecting `temp` after `allLanguages` has finished running, you get a look at what `temp` contains when `allLanguages` returns. Which is everything.

Comment: @melpomene HOLY COW MAN! I G-OT IT! ...I just ran this with external file instead of running it in the console as I used to, and stopped it during the loop and consoled log the temp! OMFG! But I thought it should output each loop the `console.log(temp)`, because it's inside of it, I'm guessing it some async magic, isn't? Oh well... thanks for getting this to my brain buddy! A LOT!

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object as hash table for collecting the languages and use anotherr `forEach` for the language of a single user after checking if this property exist and if it is an array.

Inside of the callback assign a `true` to the property with the language and at the end take the keys of the hash table and return all languages.

```js
function allLanguages() {
    var final = {};
    users.forEach(function (val) {
        if (Array.isArray(val.favoriteLanguages)) {
            val.favoriteLanguages.forEach(function (language) {
                final[language] = true;
            });
        }
    });
    return Object.keys(final);
}

var users = [{ username: 'Alex', favoriteLanguages: ['JavaScript', 'JavaScript', 'C++'], }, { username: 'Bob', favoriteLanguages: ['JavaScript', 'JavaScript', 'PHP'], }, { username: 'Mia', favoriteLanguages: ['JavaScript', 'JavaScript', 'JavaScript', 'JavaScript'], }, { username: 'David', favoriteLanguages: ['C#', 'C++', 'JavaScript'], }, { username: 'Lee', favoriteLanguages: ['JavaScript', 'JavaScript', 'Swift'] }];
   
console.log(allLanguages());
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.